# JSON - Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home/migrande/public_html/sample.php on line 14

Tags: php, json

Can anyone fix this code? I want to load all the data from the database using php json... but how i can achieve it?

```
<?php   require_once 'include/db_functions.php'; $db = new DB_Functions();



        $user = $db->getID();

        $response["products"] = array();
    if($user){
        while ($user) {

        $productstbl = array();
            $productstb["product_name"] = $user["product_name"];

            array_push($response["products"], $user);
            }
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in updating!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

?>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [ Allowed memory size ] errors, mostly occurs when there is an infinite loop.

Comment: do you know how to fix this?

Comment: is that the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way in your code where you set your `$user` variable to `FALSE`?

because as I see it, you are having an infinite loop:

```
while ($user){
    ....
    ....
    //You shoul have a way to set $user to false since it is your flag
    $user = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample.php

```
<?php   require_once 'include/db_functions.php'; $db = new DB_Functions();



        $user = $db->getID();

        $response["products"] = array();
    if($user){
        while ($user) {

        $productstbl = array();
            $productstb["product_name"] = $user["product_name"];

            array_push($response["products"], $user);
            }
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in updating!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

?>
```

Db_Functions.php

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'db_connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }
public function getID() {
   $pro_cat_id = "101";

      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT product_name FROM products WHERE pro_cat_id = ?");
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $pro_cat_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->num_rows();


      while($user=$stmt->fetch()) {
            return $user;
        }
      $stmt->close();

   }
}?>
```

Comment: you've got an infinite loop at "while($user) { ... }" - at least i can't see where $user is ever set to false again.

Comment: where I can set the $user = false?